# Convert white space to tab in BBEdit using grep

Tags: regex, replace, bbedit

I am converting 4-white-space to single-tab in BBEdit using grep. I am converting white space in Python code to tabs. Following works fine:

```
find:[^\S\r]{4}   replace:\t
```

However, why the following is removing carriage return. Should not it give the same result.

```
find:\s{4} replace:\t
```

Comment: You can certainly do this with grep, but BBEdit has a convenient [entab/detab command](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/featurestext.html) (Text -> Entab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^\S\r]{4}` means "4 characters being either not (not whitespace) or not carriage return: you can simplify it as "4 chars (whitespace or not carriage return)".

But carriage return matches whitespace. So negating \r has no effect: it can be furthermore simplified as 4 whitespaces actually equivalent to `\s{4}`

So you asked for `[\t\n ]{4}`

But that doesn't make sense, as no tabulation, carriage return or newline chars should be replaced in your case

you probably want `[ ]{4}`: 4 explicit space characters only.